# How to control safety nets in discovery writing

Tags: creative-writing, technique

Even though discovery writing is about letting the story go without interference, you still don't want the characters to get killed in the first chapter.

For this exists safety nets, **people, objects, or forces that protect the protagonists**. Three MacGuffins a day keeps George R. R. Martin at bay.

Problems arose when we use people as safety nets, sure they counter any and everything, but in (my) the worst case scenario they've got no strings on them that would hold their power down. These are typically stuff like Elminster from [*Forgotten Realms*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/TabletopGame/ForgottenRealms) or the Giant Eagles from [*Lord of the Rings*](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Film/TheLordOfTheRings). Their ability to solve the plot upon a whim makes them an implacable force, that can only be countered with an even stronger villain, said stronger villains will eat the protags for dinner. And we're back at where we started. Very specific weaknesses, like the One Ring's corrupting influence that is quadratically proportional to the user's power level, can't work on either side. Reasons: "Nomen est omen."

Removing them and their influence is sometimes possible (Giant Eagles) and sometimes not (Elminster).

**I want to keep my safety net with minimal modification, but prevent him from stealing the show. How should I do that?**

Comment: I think I know what you are asking but it is unclear. Better be sure so you get the best possible answer ;)

Comment: @TotumusMaximus Is it clearer now?

Comment: You had a scenario, you discovered a neat way to resolve it and now your act has come to an end. What I lacked in the scenario is how the character felt, what were his struggles, what did he overcome? By making your character overpowered you reduced the chance to provide character growth, which is what makes a character interesting. Why was Mephisto on the scene anyway, why wasn't he somewhere else doing bad ass stuff? Was he learning to become badass? Did he need to power up somehow?

Comment: I'm missing something in terms of the structure here, where does the mechanism that allows deviation from your expected plot come from and how does it activate?

Comment: What makes you feel that discovery writing is at odds with the author controlling the direction of the story? After all, the author can add whatever forces and impediments they want, and all the characters can do is to deal with it as best they are able. To perhaps coin an analogy, just because the sheep aren't fenced in doesn't mean they're happy to get into a fight with the sheepdogs who, after all, are the ones with the sharp teeth.

Comment: @Ash I don't really know, I just did a stat me on Kyubey and Gandalf, gave the result a propane tank, and now he refuses to die.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling It's hard SF, my hands are tied. And where would that force come from, and why haven't I ordered a drone strike on it already?

Comment: I am voting to close; this seems like a rambling word salad to me almost entirely having nothing to do with the purported question. More like critiques on existing fictional characters, in an attempt to start a debate, than an actual question about writing technique. The 'addendum' neither illuminates the situation or clarifies the question, and the commentary reply to Michael's question is senseless. Any question involving the stated characters is NOT "hard SF".

Comment: @Amadeus There's a problem with your answer, really has more to do with worldbuilding, but I edited the question to highlight it.

Answer (score 6):

As a discovery writer, I echo Michael's comment, I absolutely control the direction of the story.

I personally write with an end in mind; which I record as notes (not prose) about what finally happens; what is revealed, etc.

I very much do give my characters personalities and proclivities; while writing I feel like they are real people I know, and will only write for them actions, dialogue and ideas consistent with their personality. So, for an extreme example to illustrate my point, I am not going to force my virgin sidekick to volunteer to seduce a guard because that would be a convenient distraction. My devout priest isn't cutting any throats.

But giving my characters loose reins doesn't make me obligated to follow every move that occurs to them. I aim for their most plausible (or most conflict-producing) response, but even us real people have a handful of plausible responses to deploy in most situations. We do it, we don't do it, we find a safer way, we find a more dangerous way because we are impatient. We get angry, or get angry and control ourselves. We act on our love, or hide it with nonchalance, or hide it and suffer because it is doomed or wrong or breaks a vow.

I don't mind detours, but if I as an author am much attracted to a great idea I had whilst writing a scene, I have a rule: If that makes my current notion of the ending no longer viable, I must come up with a ***better*** ending, or think harder and rewrite the scene in some other manner to preserve my current ***better*** ending. I have to choose from a different but plausible reaction for my character(s). If that seems impossible, and I've written myself into a corner, then I unwind more of the story until I am no longer in a corner.

When I am in a corner it is not that there is NO ending if I keep writing, it is that I won't know the ending or I know it won't be good; e.g. I write reasonably happy endings. I will note that Stephen King is a discovery writer that does the same thing; while writing *The Stand* he said he discarded months of work because he wrote himself into a corner.

I control the story. I know good stories will fit pretty well into the three act structure and their timing points; that is something I expect to see emerge as I am writing; another compass to keep me on path. Unlike plotters I don't plan these ahead of time; but the three act structure was derived by analyzing a lot of pre-existing successful stories and taking averages; it *describes* what successful storytellers were doing *naturally,* by instinct and experience. So I have a "feel" for how long my hero needs to show us her normal world, when she needs to be ejected from it, when it is time for her path to change and something new to happen.

If you don't have a feel for that yet; read up on the three act structure and where the inflection points are.

Comment: Don't refrain from an edit on my account. This is general advice, I can add anything specific necessary...

Comment: Thx. I edited the question, sorry for the inconvinience.

Comment: While this is a good answer to a not so good question, answering a question while voting to close it is usually discouraged or the subject of much debate. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4283 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209085 .

Comment: @FoxElemental Why I voted to close: The question changed several times; initially the topic I gathered from the first text was, essentially, about "runaway discovery writing", in the sense that if the characters do whatever they want, they end up shorting out the plot. Then it was modified increasingly to a stream-of-consciousness word salad of complete and irrelevant nonsense; which this particular user is prone to do. Then I gave up, and voted to close. Edits make it no better, the references and terminology are opaque and unhelpful. I withdrew my initial benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @FoxElemental That said, the common wisdom in writing is about plotting and I find too few resources for discovery writing, some explanations of which are highly derogatory. So I leave my answer as something people might find helpful if they search for discovery writing as an alternative to stultifying plotting techniques, or controlling the plot while discovery writing.